# How do I call sqlite database from another Class and file?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

In my main.dart I've got a database that's getting created every time there's an App update. It has following code:

```
class DbClass {
  void favoriteDBInitializer() async {
    final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'favorite.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE favorite(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, isFavorite INTEGER)",
        );
      },
      version: 2,
    );
    for (var i = 0; i < AppBrain().contentList.length; i++) {
      Future<void> insertFavorite(Favorite favorite) async {
        final Database db = await database;
        await db.insert(
          'favorite',
          favorite.toMap(),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
        );
      }

      final listEntry = Favorite(
        id: AppBrain().contentList[i].imageNumber,
        isFavorite: 0,
      );

      await insertFavorite(listEntry);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in another File and class I want to call this database but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
  Future<List<Favorite>> favorite() async {
    final Database db = DbClass().database;

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('favorite');

    // Convert the List<Map<String, dynamic> into a List<Dog>.
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Favorite(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        isFavorite: maps[i]['isFavorite'],
      );
    });
  }
```

final Database db = DbClass().database; is the important line. DbClass().database was one of my attempts that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the class import on the top of the main.dart?

```
import 'package:<your database file .dart>';
```

You need to make an explicit initialization method that needs to be called by the user of your class like:

```
var db = new DbClass();
await db.favoriteDBInitializer();
```